# Java-SOAP Request Body Elements Order issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, axis, soap-client

I am trying to consume the SOAP Web Services so generated the classes from wsdl using AXIS.

I have done the implementation for SOAP Client and calling the SOAP Server. The SOAP Client is able to hit the SOAP Server but the Body order of request is changing while going into SOAP Server from SOAP Client.

Please find the details as below:

SOAP UI Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prim="http://..../..Services">
        <soapenv:Header />
        <soapenv:Body>
          <prim:UserList>
            <prim:XMLRequest>
              <prim:Header>
                <prim:MessageID>1</prim:MessageID>
                <prim:CorrelationID>1</CorrelationID>
              </prim:Header>
              <prim:Number>1</prim:Number>
            </prim:XMLRequest>
          </prim:UserList>
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Client sending Request to Server:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
          <UserList xmlns="hhttp://..../..Services">
            <XMLRequest>
            <Number>1</Number>
              <header>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <CorrelationID>1</CorrelationID>
              </header>
            </XMLRequest>
          </UserList>
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>


Code: 

 public  UserListResponse UserListService(UserList request)
            throws RemoteException, ServiceException {


        UserListRequest xmlRequest = new UserListRequest();

        Header reqHeader = request.getXMLRequest().getHeader();

        Header header = new Header();

        header.setCorrelationID(reqHeader.getCorrelationID());
        header.setMessageID(reqHeader.getMessageID());

        xmlRequest.setHeader(header);

        return soapStub.UserList(xmlRequest);

    }
```

UserListRequest Code:

```
/**
 * <p>Java class for UserListRequest complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="UserListRequest">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{http://..../..Services}APIArguments">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="Reference" type="{http://..../..Services}UserListReferenceTypes"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Number" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>

 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserListRequest", propOrder = {
    "reference",
    "number"
})
public class UserListRequest extendsAPIArguments  implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "Reference", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected UserListReferenceTypes reference;
    @XmlElement(name = "Number")
    protected String number;


    /**
     * Gets the value of the reference property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link UserListReferenceTypes }
     *     
     */
    public UserListReferenceTypes getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the reference property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link UserListReferenceTypes }
     *     
     */
    public void setReference(UserListReferenceTypes value) {
        this.reference = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the number property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the number property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setNumber(String value) {
        this.number = value;
    }



 // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(UserListRequest.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "UserListRequest"));
        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("reference");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "Reference"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "UserListReferenceTypes"));
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("number");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "Number"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);

    }

    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Serializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Deserializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }
}
```

Header Code:

```
/**
 * <p>Java class for Header complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="Header">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="MessageID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="CorrelationID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="SystemID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="RequestorID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="InstitutionID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Header", propOrder = {
    "messageID",
    "correlationID",
    "systemID",
    "requestorID"
})
public class Header {

    @XmlElement(name = "MessageID")
    protected String messageID;
    @XmlElement(name = "CorrelationID")
    protected String correlationID;
    @XmlElement(name = "SystemID")
    protected String systemID;
    @XmlElement(name = "RequestorID")
    protected String requestorID;

    public Header() {
    }

    public Header(
            java.lang.String messageID,
            java.lang.String correlationID,
            java.lang.String systemID,
            java.lang.String requestorID) {
            this.messageID = messageID;
            this.correlationID = correlationID;
            this.systemID = systemID;
            this.requestorID = requestorID;

     }
    /**
     * Gets the value of the messageID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getMessageID() {
        return messageID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the messageID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setMessageID(String value) {
        this.messageID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the correlationID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCorrelationID() {
        return correlationID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the correlationID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCorrelationID(String value) {
        this.correlationID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the systemID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getSystemID() {
        return systemID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the systemID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setSystemID(String value) {
        this.systemID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the requestorID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getRequestorID() {
        return requestorID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the requestorID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setRequestorID(String value) {
        this.requestorID = value;
    }

    // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(Header.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "Header","prim"));

        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("messageID");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "MessageID","prim"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("correlationID");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "CorrelationID","prim"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("systemID");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "SystemID","prim"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("requestorID");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://..../..Services", "RequestorID","prim"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();

    }

    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Serializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Deserializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }



}
```

Axis is using Serializer & deSerializer to convert into xml and vice versa.

Can anyone please suggest on this.

Comment: can you add UserListRequest, Header class code?

Comment: Added Header and UserListRequest Code into the Post. Please check and help me on this. Thanks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: just change all  the @XmlElement as required For ex. @XmlElement(name = "MessageID") to @XmlElement(name = "prim:MessageID") wherever required

Comment: Actually prim is prefix of namespace. i am not understanding why we need to change as like this -@XmlElement(name = "prim:MessageID").Please explain me the purpose of this. Thanks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: Do you have package.info inside the package containing UserListRequest  and Header? if yes, add it in the question. Read this, https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.

Comment: Getting null pointer exception if added same as above. Thanks @Shubham Kadlag

Comment: Yes, But it is treating  as axis not jaxb so that is not working for me.@ Shubham Kadlag